# Google Apps Script: How to copy and automatically edit the data from a spreadsheet to others?

Tags: database, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to solve this question but despite the effort I have not advanced!

Every day I get a spreadsheet with two tabs of data. Each one has about 9 thousand rows. I need to capture the data from this worksheet and generate two new spreadsheets with one for "daily reporting" (with only the data of this day) and another for create a "database" (with all data previous results). How can I do this automatically with GAS?

I working in this code below so far, but when I will set the values in the new spreadsheet, I got error about range. :( I don't know how to declare that I want copy and set all the rows between 10 and the last with data from

```
  function getData() {
  var day = SpreadsheetApp.openById('XXXX');
  var tab1 = day.getSheets()[0];
  var tab2 = day.getSheets()[1];

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sss = ss.getSheets()[0];

  var weeks = tab1.getRange("G8").getValues();
  var dates = tab1.getRange("G9").getValues();
  var regions = tab1.getRange('A10:A').getValues();
  var locnames = tab1.getRange('B10:B').getValues();
  var locnums = tab1.getRange('C10:C').getValues();
  var divisions = tab1.getRange('D10:D').getValues();
  var depnums = tab1.getRange('E10:E').getValues();
  var depnames = tab1.getRange('F10:F').getValues();
  var saless = tab1.getRange('G10:G').getValues();
  var qtys = tab2.getRange('G10:G').getValues();

  var datestart = sss.getRange('A2').setValues(dates);
  var dateend = sss.getRange('B2').setValues(dates);
  var week = sss.getRange('C2').setValues(weeks);
  var region = sss.getRange('D2:D').setValues(regions);
  var locname = sss.getRange('E2:E').setValues(locnames);
  var locnum = sss.getRange('F2:F').setValues(locnums);
  var division = sss.getRange('G2:G').setValues(divisions);
  var depnum = sss.getRange('H10:H').setValues(depnums);
  var depname = sss.getRange('I2:I').setValues(depnames);
  var sales = sss.getRange('J2:J').setValues(saless);
  var qty = sss.getRange('K2:K').setValues(qtys);

 }
```

If anyone can help me, thank you immensely.

I put a spreadsheet in the link to illustrate the format of sheets and what I need to do. The first two tabs are the same as the ones I get. And in the next two  tabs(daily_report, database) are the worksheets that I want to get separately with the code.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_iz0oansAfINosV2qNoDG0QMNpGS1bp1AL5kJQztRtc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: You want to make 2 exact copies of 1 sheet? Check [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet?hl=nl#copyTo(Spreadsheet))

Comment: Hey Casper, thanks for responding, but in fact I need to make 1 spreadsheet that get data from these 2 sheets and I will take for report about that day; and another spreadsheet that must save all the days before. Maybe I was not clear, sorry for this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The target range must be matched to the source range, or there will be an error.  The length and width of the target range must be the same as the source data.  You can use the data to set the length (number of rows) and width (number of columns)

### Parameters:

> range(Start Row, Start Column, Number of Rows, Number of Columns)

### Code:

```
var regions = tab1.getRange('A10:A').getValues();
var region = sss.getRange(2,4,regions.length,regions[0].length).setValues(regions);
```

Comment: hey @Sandy Good, really, really thank you! The code worked perfectly! And, if I could ask one more question, I´d like to know how can I get automatically the two spreadsheets:
1 - a spreadsheet with the data of the day (last update), and the new data have to subscribe the previou data.
2 - a spreadsheet with all data, in this case, the new data must increment on the last row, and will storage all the previous data.

Comment: It's better to ask a new question, or maybe ask the question in the Apps Script Community:  [Link to Apps Script community](https://plus.google.com/communities/102471985047225101769)